# Insert data into BigQuery from a Google Script : Encountered ""

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I am trying to import data from a Google Spreadsheet to BigQuery, via Google App Script. I can download data, but I have an error when I try to do INSERT INTO. The error message is

> Encountered "" at line 1, column 31. [Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]

Here is my code :

```
function insertRowsInBigQuery(){
var projectId = 'xxx';
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("EPC");

var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
var sqlData = "INSERT INTO ean.eanToAnalyze (EPC, EAN) VALUES (";

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  if (i > 0) {
    sqlData += ",(";
  }
  for (j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++){
    sqlData += "'" + data[i][j] + "'";
    if (j < data[0].length -1){
      sqlData += ",";
    } else {
      sqlData +=")";
    }
  }     
}

var request = {
  query: sqlData,
  writeDisposition: 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
};

var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;

// Check on status of the Query Job.
var sleepTimeMs = 500;
while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
  Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
  sleepTimeMs *= 2;
  queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
}

Logger.log(queryResults);

}
```

With almost the same function, only changing the INSERT INTO by a SELECT, I get data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error states, you need to [enable standardSQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql) to use [DML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language). The easiest way seems to be by prefixing your query:

```
var sqlData = "#standardSQL\nINSERT INTO ean.eanToAnalyze (EPC, EAN) VALUES (";
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve the same is by setting the `useLegacySql` parameter to `false`.
You can update the request variable as follows:

```
var request = {
  query: sqlData,
  writeDisposition: 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
  useLegacySql: false
};
```