# BigQuery errs with DELETE from AppsScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I am attempting to issue a [delete to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#delete_statement) from AppsScript:

```
  var req = {
    // gotta place the where clause else BQ abends
    query: "delete from `" + projectId + "." + datasetId + "." + tableName + "` where 1=1;"
  };

  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(req,projectId);
```

Alas, I get the following error:

`GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: 1.1 - 1.53: Unrecognized token delete. [Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)] (line 61, file "Code")`

Obviously, the problem is not "standard" syntax here, rather it appears as though the API is pre-validating the SQL statement; said validator likely does not realize `delete`s are now supported.

**What mechanism is to be used then to delete table data from AppsScript?**

Comment: *Obviously* How is that obvious?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert data into BigQuery from a Google Script : Encountered ""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56652895/insert-data-into-bigquery-from-a-google-script-encountered)

Comment: @TheMaster, sorry, in that the `delete` syntax is supported in the BQ SQL grammar as mentioned in the documentation..

Comment: @TheMaster, your reference does indeed work!  Thank you, want the answer?

Comment: Great! but ..no. Since it's a exact duplicate. There isn't anything I could add. You could upvote my other answer though:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `#standardSQL` to your sql in order to run BigQuery from an appsscript

```
var req = {
    // gotta place the where clause else BQ abends
    query: "#standardSQL \n delete from `" + projectId + "." + datasetId + "." + tableName + "` where 1=1;"
  };

  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(req,projectId);
```

The **\n** isn't technically required,  it is a formatting preference for me. When/if you look up the call in BigQuery's "Query History" it will show the commands on separate lines